# Show the external direct sum of subspaces for an identity and describe the subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be a linear operator on $V$. Consider the identity

$v=\frac12(v+f(v))+\frac12(v-f(v))$

Use this identity to show that $V=V_1\oplus V_2$ for some subspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ and describe these subspaces.

I know $V$ will be all the pairs $(v_1,v_2)$ such that $v_1\in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$. Also since it is a vector space, it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, so $V$ will also be the elements $(v_1+v_1',v_2+v_2')$ and $(av_1,av_2)$ for $v_1, v_1'\in V_1$, $v_2,v_2'\in V_2$ and $a\in K$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity tells us what the subspaces should be, $V_1=\{v+f(v)|v\in V\}$ and $V_2=\{v-f(v)|v\in V\}$. You should have no problem verifying that these are in fact subspaces and clearly $V=V_1+V_2$.

Then, if you want $V$ to be the direct sum of both spaces they must also satisfy that $V_1\cap V_2 = \{0\}$. But that's not always the case, for example consider the vector space $K^n$ with $K$ a field and the function $f(x)=\alpha x$ for some $\alpha\neq 0\in K$. Then $x+f(x) = x+\alpha x = y-f(y) = y-\alpha y$ has the nontrivial solution $x = \frac{1-\alpha}{1+\alpha}y$ whenever $\alpha\neq -1$.

So the suggested decomposition doesn't work in general